# Debian and Tomcat, why creating a dedicated user?

Tags: users, debian-wheezy, tomcat7

I was trying to install tomcat 7 on Wheezy

Looking at several guides, I noticed that almost all of them suggest to create a dedicated user.. why?

I am also asking that because I have installed tomcat 7 through the repository and I looked that I have already a user suitable for that, I guess maybe the tomcat installation itself created it

```
cat /etc/passwd
tomcat7:x:103:106::/usr/share/tomcat7:/bin/false
```

So my question is, do I need to create an (additional) user for my tomcat?

```
root@j51391:~# /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/version.sh 
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat7/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.28
Server built:   Dec 8 2012 06:51:43
Server number:  7.0.28.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     3.10.13-x86_64-jb1
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.7.0_45-b18
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
```

Comment: I think you guess correctly, and I think that user will be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a good practice to create a dedicated account for some services, specially when they are accessible over the internet or any untrusted network. So if somebody exploits a security flaw in Tomcat it's not going to compromise the whole system. (Unless he manages to escalate privileges, but that's another story)

From the Security Considerations section of Tomcat documentation:

> Tomcat should not be run under the root user. Create a dedicated user
>   for the Tomcat process and provide that user with the minimum
>   necessary permissions for the operating system. For example, it should
>   not be possible to log on remotely using the Tomcat user.

In your case, it seems like the package installer has already taken care of creating the dedicated user.